How to show that for a random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ taking value in an interval $[a,b]$, we have $\mathrm{Var}[X]\leq (\mu-a)(b-\mu)$
I was reading this paper https://salil.seas.harvard.edu/publications/when-simple-hash-functions-suffice and as part of the proof of a theorem, the authors claim that for any random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ taking values in an interval $[a,b]$, we have $$\sigma[X]\leq \sqrt{(\mu-a)(b-\mu)}\quad (1)$$ As a proof for this claim, they use the following inequality:
$$\mathrm{Var}[X] = E[(X-a)^2]-(\mu-a)^2 \leq (b-a)(\mu-a)-(\mu-a)^2$$
However, I do not understand why $$E[(X-a)^2] \leq (b-a)(\mu-a)\quad (2)$$
Given that $a\leq X \leq b$, we have $E[(X-a)^2]\leq (b-a)^2$. In addition, we have $(X-\mu)^2\leq \max((b-\mu)^2, (a-\mu)^2)$. However, this does not seem to be a lead to prove either $(1)$ or $(2)$.

Since $X\geqslant a$,  $(X-a)^2=(X-a)(X-a)\leqslant (b-a)(X-a)$. Then we derive (2) by taking expectation.
